# Several data task

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I am trying to do several data task in `for` loop

```
var loaded = false
    for root in roots {
            if !loaded {
                let URL = NSURL(string: root + "" + attr)
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                    (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    /////////////////////// implement task ///////////////
                    //////// if data loaded then "loaded" becoming true //
                }

            task.resume()
            }
    }
```

but in case of async this block of code executes more times than should.
How to fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by "more times than it should"?

Comment: I mean, I load data by first root URL, set `loaded` on true, but all requests is executing yet

Comment: Loaded isn't set to true until one of the tasks finishes. The loop will complete in milliseconds. May take a couple of seconds for the first task to finish. The tasks are all started before the first one finishes.

Comment: If you want the tasks to only start if loaded is false then you need only one operation running at a time. The first thing the operation does is check the value of loaded. The next is to start the download task.